# Regarding openimaj(Multimedia analysis in Java)

Tags: opencv, openimaj

I can see lot of integration stuff(hadoop, storm) in the openimaj source code(https://github.com/openimaj/openimaj/tree/master/streams/common-stream/src/main/java/org/openimaj/stream) plus interesting stuff in their home page documentation(http://openimaj.org/index.html). Off-course their video integration is with xuggler which is almost dead.

I am also looking some powerful multimedia analysis library in java. I know that OpenCV is the right candidate for this and under the hood, everybody uses that library for multimedia analysis.

However, I am surprised that no information on openimaj usage(as very less hit pages coming on google) is available even after so much stuff. Further, the last update on their home page is of sept 2014 that confuses me whether it is still active.

Do anyone have used that for multimedia analysis in java or any knowledge whether it is still an active project?

Comment: It's still active, although we haven't made a release in a while (check the github site for recent activity). You haven't said in your question what you want to do however; OpenIMAJ and opencv have quite different use-cases, although there is some common functionality with computer vision techniques.

Comment: Thanks Jon, my use case is to do object recognition using hadoop(still planned) but I am glad to see that its still active. I will not be hesitate to use it.